# Bootstrap popover content wrong position

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I use popover in my project, when page show on small device, popover arrow has correct position but popover content wrong.

[image]

I use col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 in parent element. popover i set it in table td tag. When browser in desktop, it show ok but in device browser it wrong. Please help me. Sorry for my bad english.

Input code:

```
 <input rel="popover" class="form-control" type="text" spellcheck="false" data-style="searchindexbox" 
  data-bind="popover:{ content:'<i class=&quot;fa fa-lightbulb-o&quot; aria-hidden=&quot;true&quot;></i> Nhập khu vực, địa điểm muốn tìm kiếm.<br/>+ Tên đường, tên phường xã, huyện... Ví dụ: go vap<br/>+ Sau đó chọn từ danh sách gợi ý.<br/>Hoặc chọn trực tiếp từ danh sách tỉnh thành bên dưới.', html: 'true', trigger:'focus' }, typeahead: { source: Suggestions, updater: Updater, minLength: 3, items: 'all' }, value: SearchText" />
```

Javascript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                var defaultOptions = {};        
                options = $.extend(true, {}, defaultOptions, options);
                options.placement = function (context, source){
                    return 'auto top';
                };
                $(element).popover(options);
                $(element).on("change paste keyup", function() {
                    if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
                        $(element).popover('hide');
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: Please go through once [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show us some relavant cde

Comment: I detected problem appear when <input/> tag has max-width and width 100%. But i can't found solution fix it.